# How can I create grouped or pair-wise box plots in Vega-Lite?

Tags: vega-lite

Like this one :
https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/265-grouped-boxplot-with-ggplot2/

I tried facets and color channels and composition,
 but it did not work out as I liked to.

My  use case it to easily compare the grouped means, so I need the grouped box plots side-by-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of column and x encodings. Here is an example with the vega-datasets population data ([vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zEgVwE4BsVTkQHoAHAexIxwQEsyA7AOgCsBnByAXwBpwoBbWFgDW+UBAiR4ATxIBTfJABGZAB4kcZeJF4Soc1fDn1tqSPxr0AtINWQ+PPpGMBjMtEsBzMX0lucGPz0YpAAZjRyONCKsJ4K3FKyCmZkWB70sHiOepDSPnqS4ZHRZvIUOPG+EonyigCOGLAmNIjwNABulQVQsKo0rCFt8BWK5JTUbRycVdnVdqjiBWERUYqsBjpVkjK1ZvRkFhl4M7rV-qn5S0WrZut2pzk7yVD7h5n2etMQ09NAA)):

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/population.json"},
  "mark": {
    "type": "boxplot",
    "extent": "min-max"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "column": {"field": "age","type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {
      "field": "people",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "population"}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "sex",
      "type": "nominal"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "sex",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]